# Solving Second Order Differential Equation with Discrete Time Data

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, discrete-mathematics

Given the Second Order Differential Equation:

$$ m\ddot{x}+c\dot{x}+kx = \mathrm{F}_{external}^{} $$

where $ m, c, k $  are constants and $\mathrm{F}_{external}^{}$ is buffer of external force taken at 48Hz.

Numeric solution is needed for $x$ in a form of a similar buffer.

Ty

Comment: I don't get your question. You can solve this equation explicitely even for $F$ being a step function. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes. $\mathrm{F}_{external}^{}$ is given at set time intervals. Need x at the same time intervals.

Comment: Could you solve the equation if it was a continuous $F$?

Comment: No idea. I will check the FDM like here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wUFOzGMHues&ab_channel=GeeKeeCeeBee